# Good book recommendations on trigonometry

Tags: reference-request, trigonometry, book-recommendation

I need to find a good book on trigonometry, I was using trigonometry demystified but I got sad when I read this line:

> Now that you know how the circular functions are defined, you might wonder how the values are calculated. The answer: with an electronic calculator!

I know a book which seems to be really good: Loney's Plane Trigonometry, I'm just not sure if the book is up to date.

Comment: https://archive.org/details/treatiseonplanet00hobs

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You might want to look at the following book references:

- Trigonometry, I.M. Gelfand, Mark Saul
- Trigonometry Refresher (Dover Books on Mathematics), A. Albert Klaf, Mathematics
- Schaum's Outline of Trigonometry, 5th Edition, Robert Moyer, Frank Ayres
- Trigonometry, 8th Edition, Ron Larson  ($$$)
- Advanced Trigonometry, by C.V. Durell, A. Robson

You might also want to review online items. For example:

- [*Khan Academy*](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/trigonometry)
- [*Trig WikiBooks*](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Trigonometry)
- [*Open Course Ware on Trigonometry*](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&ie=UTF-8#hl=en&spell=1&q=opencourseware+trigonometry&sa=X&ei=cZAnUcqULMraigLMlICQBg&ved=0CC8QvwUoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&bvm=bv.42768644,d.cGE&fp=144f07a7d05f8158&ion=1&biw=1400&bih=731&safe=images)

Enjoy!

Comment: It was made community wiki (sometimes book recommendation requests are considered "soft" or having no one correct answer, so although they are relevant to the site, sometimes it is flagged (some users do this) to make it CW...after which, no reputation is gained for the asker or the user.  A person can also make his/her answer community wiki...

Answer (score 13):

Michael Corral's [Trigonometry](http://mecmath.net/trig/) is excellent, building geometric foundations before transitioning to analytical aspects. It also helps that it's absurdly good-looking. It comes with a [GNU Free Documentation License](http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/fdl.html) too.

Answer (score 12):

Plane Trigonometry by S.L. Loney is the best book for trigonometry.The concepts are explained in a very good manner in the book.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to learn trigonometry from basic level then S.L.Loney's Plane Trigonometry is the best one. It takes us through various levels of understanding trigonometry gradually without the feel of difficulty.

Answer (score 4):

An underrated source that's also low priced is *Precalculus In A Nutshell* by George F. Simmons: This was the last of the amazing textbooks by Simmons, which include such classics as *An Introduction To Topology and Modern Analysis*  and  *Differential Equations with Applications and Historical Notes.*  Each of these books is marked by Simmons’ unique combination of detailed exposition, lively prose and conceptual clarity. This is his last and most elementary book and it’s no exception. Simmons’ purpose of this beautiful book is to condense into a readable, lucid treatment what he deemed essential for high school students to learn before learning basic calculus.He covers just what he deems necessary in algebra, geometry and trigonometry for mastering calculus-and I think his choice of topics is very good indeed. I think you'll find it very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Are you only interested in a Book, can I suggest a material that has lecture notes? A video? :) It has been an excellent learning material for many I know of.

[ThinkWell Trignometry](http://www.thinkwell.com/instructor/product/trigonometry)

As for a book, try this out as well:

- Plane and Spherical Trigonometry

Comment: Yes. Anything that teaches me trigonometry will suffice.

Answer (score 2):

I also suggest the thinkwell but as a supplement not the main course. Larson is good but ridiculously expensive and klaf & durell are a little too much if don't already know something.  Gelfand & Loney are generally a more rigorous and conceptually clear treatment of the subject.  I have one other suggestion, which is free "Stitz & Zeager,  trigonometry". This is also very good, only complaint a little dry and the appearance too spartan, even for a math book !

Answer (score 1):

What about Trigonometry by Charles P. McKeague and
Mark D. Turner?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing changed much in basic Trigonometry for a century. Of Loney's book genre is another:

Henry Sinclair Hall, Samuel Ratcliffe Knight, Macmillan and Company, 1893 - Plane trigonometry - 404 pages

Answer (score 1):

Best trigonometry books which i read А.Ф.БЕРМАНТ, Н.М.БЕСКИН and И.М.ГЕЛФАНД trigonometry books but  in russian you can also look at

1.Palmer C.I, Leigh C.w plane and spherical trigonometry old but really good book and plenty of physics applications
2. I.M Gelfand (russian version is much more rigorous)
3. Bettinger A.K Algebra and trigonometry
4. Swokowski E.W, Cole J.A Algebra and Trigonometry

Answer (score 1):

For those who understand Russian, the book "Спецыальный курс тригонометрии" by S. I. Novoselov ("Special course on Trigonometry") will be of a great value, alongside other wonderful books mentioned here.