# recommended Books for trigonometry?

Tags: trigonometry, book-recommendation

I am a first year engineer student here in my country we have a first preparatory year so I was looking for a deep understanding book for trigonometry

Because I have always had a hard time with this hyperbolic and cosecant and inverse functions thing

So if any one could recommend a set of books **in order** to read to really understand and have a deep look at this subject would be great

Comment: Also https://math.stackexchange.com/q/310980/29335

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't go wrong with any of Gelfand's books. I would recommend his book "Trigonometry."

[https://www.amazon.com/Trigonometry-I-M-Gelfand/dp/0817639144](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0817639144)